# Variáveis fora da função

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou usando o código abaixo para ler PDFs com a interface do tkinter:

```
import io
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry('800x600')
janela.title('Envio de Email automatizado')
inserepdf = Label(janela, text='Buscar pdf')
inserepdf.pack()


def abrirArquivo():
    arquivo = filedialog.askopenfilename()


botaoAbrir = Button(janela, text="Abrir Arquivo", command=abrirArquivo)
botaoAbrir.pack()


def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
    with open(arquivo, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
    # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

    if text:
        return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    texto = str(extract_text_from_pdf(''))

    print(texto.split())

janela.mainloop()
```

Porém não consigo fazer o programa ler o pdf importado na função abrirArquivo() , informa que a variável arquivo não existe, porém não consegui definir ela como global ou nonlocal, e não sei como usar a váriável dentro da função extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path). Se puderem me ajudar, agradecerei muito.

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque a variável está declarada na função como uma variável local, para vc utilizar essa variável em outro lugar você tem que deixar essa variável `global`, para se utilizar uma variável `global` dentro de uma função, é necessário declará-la como `global` dentro dessa função assim:

```
arquivo=""
def abrirArquivo():
    global arquivo
    arquivo = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    global arquivo
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
    with open(arquivo, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
    # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

    if text:
        return text
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas como informei, não consigo declarar como global a varável. Quando tento como no seu código, acontece o seguinte erro:                 with open(arquivo, 'rb') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: bom não sou especialista em tkinter mas dei uma olhada mais aprofundada no seu código e acho que é mais uma questão de estrutura e organização do código e principalmente das funções, vou deixar um exemplo [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/LuxuriousLoathsomeAmoebas) de como organizei o código e deixei ele funcionando.

Comment: Obrigado, desculpe a demora! Realmente, também organizei e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: De nada!! Que bom que funcionou!